# What character is this and what game is it from?

Tags: game-identification

I've had this image as my profile picture for a while on steam, and it’s in the steam list of profile pictures, but I’m not sure from which game is it nor who is this character. I've tried with google image search and all but nothing helped. See if you can identify it.

[image: This is the character from the game]

Comment: Honestly I am not sure it is from a game, reverse image searching isn't returning anything for me besides steam profiles.

Comment: And exactly that's my steam profile. While creating the profile i had selected this pic from steam's profile pic. list. But i'm unable to find it anymore :(

Comment: @Ramirez If it is from the steam list of profile pics, then it have to be from a game.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It is the [Assassin](http://mondaynightcombat.wikia.com/wiki/Assassin) from the game Super Monday Night Combat/Monday Night Combat.

Comment: +1 Nice find on that one. I completely forgot about SMNC.

Comment: @Ramirez Never played the Super Monday Night Combat one only the Monday Night Combat one, but it was my favorite character :)

Comment: Did this game die an horrific death? When I tried to play it there was no one around (a couple of years ago though).

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I remember a few years ago my friends who still played it complained that it was overrun with hackers. And it's inevitable that all online multiplayer games die.

Comment: @Random832 Simple math right? There's a fixed base of users that play online games, and they can only distribute their time between games finitely. As new games come out, old ones forcibly get pushed out. It's also a snowball effect. Once users start leaving, more start leaving because the value in an online game depends on other players